# Sync subfolders correctly with rsync

Tags: ssh, rsync

I have this folder structure:

```
- folder1
- - subfolder1
- - - sub-subfolder 1
- - - sub-subfolder 2
- - - sub-subfolder 3
- - subfolder 2
    ...
- folder2
- - subfolder1
- - - sub-subfolder 1
- - - sub-subfolder 2
- - - sub-subfolder 3
- - subfolder 2
    ...
```

`folder1` is the old system. `folder2` is the new system. I need to copy `folder1/subfolder1/sub-subfolder 1` to `folder2/subfolder1/sub-subfolder 1`, but dont overwrite existing files or existing folders.

How can I do this with rsync?

Answer (score 0):

use rsync with option `--ignore-existing`
to ignore existing files in destination